# How do you add "3 months" to a datetime.date object in python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

### Python date calculations, where art thou?

I have a python app that needs to plot out dates every three months for several years.  It's important that the dates occur exactly 4 times a year, and that the dates occur on the same day each year as much as possible, and that the dates occur on the same day of the month as much as possible, and that the dates be as close to "3 months" apart as they can be (which is a moving target, especially on leap year).  Unfortunately, `datetime.timedelta` doesn't support months!

Is there a "standard" way to do this calculation in python???

### The SQL way?

If worst comes to worst, I will punt and have my app ask PostgreSQL, who does have nice built-in support for date calculations, for the answer like this:

```
# select ('2010-11-29'::date + interval '3 months')::date;
    date    
------------
 2011-02-28
(1 row)
```

Comment: Depends on what you consider a month. Is it always 90 days?

Comment: Why not just fix the dates?  For instance, use Jan 1, April 1, July 1, Oct 1.  That satisfies the "exactly 4 times a year" and you don't have to pick the 1st, it could be the 5th or the 10th, or whatever day you choose.  The only downside is Q1 gets 90 or 91 days, Q2 gets 91, Q3 and Q4 both get 92, but that's good enough for government work.

Comment: FYI, I ended up using PostgresSQL for all my date calculations, because it was by far the nicest, sanest calculations in the cleanest way.  I marked the best python answer below, though.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you're looking for exact or "more precise" dates, you're probably better off checking out [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

Quick example:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> import datetime
>>> TODAY = datetime.date.today()
>>> TODAY
datetime.date(2012, 3, 6)
```

Now add 3 months to `TODAY`, observe that it matches the day exactly (Note that `relativedelta(months=3)` and `relativedelta(month=3)` have different behaviors. Make sure to use `months` for these examples!).

```
>>> three_mon_rel = relativedelta(months=3)
>>> TODAY + three_mon_rel
datetime.date(2012, 6, 6)
```

And it stays consistent throughout the course of a year. Literally every three months, on the day (had to keep adding because for some reason multiplying a `relativedelta` and adding it to a `datetime.date` object throws a `TypeError`):

```
>>> TODAY + three_mon_rel + three_mon_rel
datetime.date(2012, 9, 6)
>>> TODAY + three_mon_rel + three_mon_rel + three_mon_rel
datetime.date(2012, 12, 6)
>>> TODAY + three_mon_rel + three_mon_rel + three_mon_rel + three_mon_rel
datetime.date(2013, 3, 6)
```

Whereas the [mVChr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246616/mvchr)'s suggested solution, while definitely "good enough", drifts slightly over time:

```
>>> three_mon_timedelta = datetime.timedelta(days=3 * 365/12)
>>> TODAY + three_mon_timedelta
datetime.date(2012, 6, 5)
```

And over the course of a year, the day of month keeps sliding:

```
>>> TODAY + three_mon_timedelta * 2
datetime.date(2012, 9, 4)
>>> TODAY + three_mon_timedelta * 3
datetime.date(2012, 12, 4)
>>> TODAY + three_mon_timedelta * 4
datetime.date(2013, 3, 5)
```

Comment: `relativedelta(months=3)` and `relativedelta(month=3)` have really different behaviors, I've struggle a little to see that I've missed an 's' on 'month', maybe that's good to be mentioned in your very good answer :)

Comment: Good call! I updated the response to reflect your comment, and fixed a typo while I was at it. :)

Comment: big +1 to `dateutil` module

Comment: This is a little drifty with months with less days.  Instead of `TODAY + delta + delta ...`, you should do `delta + delta + TODAY`.  This ensures that even if there's a February in the way, you'll land on the best day possible in the month you end in.

Answer (score 10):

```
import datetime

some_date = datetime.date.today()
three_months = datetime.timedelta(3*365/12)
print (some_date + three_months).isoformat()
# => '2012-06-01'
```

Then "normalize" every new year to the original date's day (unless Feb 29)

Comment: This is a "good enough" solution. I like the use of `3 * 365 / 12` vs.  `3 * 30`.

Comment: I get `2012-06-05` is your date set wrong?  Because today is the 6th of March.

Comment: Also, three_months here is just 91 days exactly, unless you do `3*365.0/12`.  Then it's 91 days and 6 hours.

Comment: Oops, yes, tested on my VM.  Thanks.

Comment: can you explain why we need to do month*days-in-a-year/months-in-a-year ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Python standard libraries, i.e. without `dateutil` or others, and solving the 'February 31st' problem:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_months(date, months):
    months_count = date.month + months

    # Calculate the year
    year = date.year + int(months_count / 12)

    # Calculate the month
    month = (months_count % 12)
    if month == 0:
        month = 12

    # Calculate the day
    day = date.day
    last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    if day > last_day_of_month:
        day = last_day_of_month

    new_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return new_date
```

Testing:

```
>>>date = datetime.date(2018, 11, 30)

>>>print(date, add_months(date, 3))
(datetime.date(2018, 11, 30), datetime.date(2019, 2, 28))

>>>print(date, add_months(date, 14))
(datetime.date(2018, 12, 31), datetime.date(2020, 2, 29))
```

Comment: Doesn't work for negative values of `months` if months <= -date.month. For example, add_months(datetime.date(2020,7,30), -7) = datetime.date(2020, 12, 30).

Comment: This has a bug where the month is 11 and you try to add one months `add_months(datetime.date(2020, 11, 1), 1)` outputs `datetime.date(2021, 12, 1)` . The fix is to change `int(months_count / 12)` to `int(months_count / 13)` or better yet `months_count // 13`

Answer (score 2):

The answers from @david-ragazzi and @mikedugas77 work well with positive values for `months`, but not if `months <= -date.month`. Here's a modification that should work even for negative month offsets:

```py
import calendar
import datetime

def add_months(date, months):
    months_count = date.year * 12 + date.month + months - 1

    # Calculate the year
    year = months_count // 12

    # Calculate the month
    month = months_count % 12 + 1

    # Calculate the day
    day = date.day
    last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    if day > last_day_of_month:
        day = last_day_of_month

    new_date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return new_date
```

With some tests using today's date:

```py
date = datetime.date(2020, 7, 30)
assert add_months(date, -12) == datetime.date(2019, 7, 30)
assert add_months(date, -11) == datetime.date(2019, 8, 30)
assert add_months(date, -10) == datetime.date(2019, 9, 30)
assert add_months(date, -9) == datetime.date(2019, 10, 30)
assert add_months(date, -8) == datetime.date(2019, 11, 30)
assert add_months(date, -7) == datetime.date(2019, 12, 30)
assert add_months(date, -6) == datetime.date(2020, 1, 30)
assert add_months(date, -5) == datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)
assert add_months(date, -4) == datetime.date(2020, 3, 30)
assert add_months(date, -3) == datetime.date(2020, 4, 30)
assert add_months(date, -2) == datetime.date(2020, 5, 30)
assert add_months(date, -1) == datetime.date(2020, 6, 30)
assert add_months(date, 0) == datetime.date(2020, 7, 30)
assert add_months(date, 1) == datetime.date(2020, 8, 30)
assert add_months(date, 2) == datetime.date(2020, 9, 30)
assert add_months(date, 3) == datetime.date(2020, 10, 30)
assert add_months(date, 4) == datetime.date(2020, 11, 30)
assert add_months(date, 5) == datetime.date(2020, 12, 30)
assert add_months(date, 6) == datetime.date(2021, 1, 30)
assert add_months(date, 7) == datetime.date(2021, 2, 28)
assert add_months(date, 8) == datetime.date(2021, 3, 30)
assert add_months(date, 9) == datetime.date(2021, 4, 30)
assert add_months(date, 10) == datetime.date(2021, 5, 30)
assert add_months(date, 11) == datetime.date(2021, 6, 30)
assert add_months(date, 12) == datetime.date(2021, 7, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function that may be able to help you:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_months(date, months):

    # Determine the month and year of the new date
    month, year = (date + relativedelta(months=months)).month, (date + relativedelta(months=months)).year

    # Determine the day of the new date
    # If the day of the current date is at the end of the month,
    # the day of the new date should also be at the end of the month
    if(date.day == calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]):
        day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
    else:
        day = date.day

    new_date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
    return new_date
```

It supports adding negative months as well (i.e. subtracting months).

Here is some sample usage that illustrates how to obtain 2021 and 2022 dates as per your specs:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)

# Initialse a list to hold the dates
dates = [0]*8

# Obtain the dates
for i in range(0, len(dates)):
    dates[i] = add_months(a, 3*i)

dates
```

Comment: Can you also include a sample code of its usage to solve the original problem?

Comment: Have a look now. Added a sample of 2021 and 2022

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. So, I am just going to write up a solution that fixes a bug in the solution that David Ragazzi posted.

The error occurs when you add enough months to get to a December date. The year is 1 too many.

For example, `add_months(date.fromisoformat('2020-01-29'), 11)` returns 2021 instead of 2020. I fixed the issue by changing the line starting with `year =`.

```
    import datetime
    import calendar
    def add_months(dateInput, months):
        months_count = dateInput.month + months

        # Calculate the year
        year = dateInput.year + int((months_count-1) / 12)

        # Calculate the month
        month = (months_count % 12)
        if month == 0:
            month = 12

        # Calculate the day
        day = dateInput.day
        last_day_of_month = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
        if day > last_day_of_month:
            day = last_day_of_month

        new_date = date(year, month, day)
        return new_date
```

Comment: Doesn't work for negative values of `months` if months <= -date.month. For example, add_months(datetime.date(2020,7,30), -7) = datetime.date(2020, 12, 30).